# Value of type 'QuerySnapshot' has no member 'data' error will appear

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Value of type 'QuerySnapshot' has no member 'data' error will appear.

But I am in trouble because I do not know why.

I would be pleased if you could give me a professor.

```
private func getTextData(userID: Array<Any>, image: Array<Any>) {
    for user in userID {
        self.db.collection("users").document(self.fireAuthUID).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot3, error) in
            if error != nil {
                return
            } else {
                guard let data = snapshot3?.data() else { return }
                self.teamIDFromFirebase = data["teamID"] as? String ?? ""
                self.db.collection("diary").document(self.teamIDFromFirebase).collection("diaries").addSnapshotListener({ (query, err) in
                    if err != nil {
                        return
                    } else {
                        let doc = query?.data() ←　Value of type 'QuerySnapshot' has no member 'data'

                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

QuerySnapshot contains docs not data as is documented here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.

> docs
>
> non-null Array of non-null QuerySnapshot
>
> An array of all the documents in the `QuerySnapshot`.

To simply obtain docs from query use `query.docs`. In your case `query?.docs`

Comment: I'd like to obtain data, what should I do?